# Add components to Spring 3 via javacode

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, apache-camel

Is there a way to add the ActiveMQ component via javacode in Spring's applicationConfig XML?

My main goal is to pick up he "brokerURL" from an external property file. But the property file is not a standard property file, its XML based so have to parse it appropriately and get the properties.

```
<!-- COMPONENT BEANS -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You can get properties from all sorts of sources (getting it from somewhere exotic might require code) but I'm having trouble working out what sort of configuration you're using as the main one. Is it mainly XML-based or mainly Java/annotation based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways.

one is truly programmatic, like this:

```
org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent amq = new org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent();
amq.setConnectionFactory(new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(parseOddXml(brokerXMLConfigFile)));
camelContext.addComponent("activemq", amq);
```

given you have a camel context aware bean somewhere to initialize your components.

Otherwise, you could perhaps just wire up the connection factory from elsewhere and have it injected into the XML config on the ActiveMQ component.

Something like this perhaps

```
 @Configuration
 class MyAMQConfig{
   public @Bean ActiveMQConnectionFactory createCF(){
      String brokerURI = parseOddXml(brokerConfigFile); // or whatever logic here.
      return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURI);
   }
 }
```

then something like this in XML:

```
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activeMQConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Or any other way, since there are multiple ways to wire beans and interact with the Camel Context.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. This is very helpful! I'm looking to go about it the 2nd way "wire up the connection factory from elsewhere and have it injected". I set up MyAMQConfig class and created a ref bean.. but getting this error

Comment: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springf
ramework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.test.properties.MyAMQConfig' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory';

Comment: Ah figured it out.. needed this property <property name="connectionFactory">
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"></bean>
  </property>
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just extend the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class so that i can get properties from your XML file (use commons-configuration or some other package like that), and put an instance of that in your spring config?

Then just used standard property replacement.